# Set date on each button title and if user click it again then user will able to change it again

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

My problem is that how to put date on each button title.
I want user to input date on each button click
and if he will again select the button he will be able to change date again...

Please see attached image:

[image]

I am totally confused
Please suggest me a solution

Thanks In advance...

Comment: u can add a time picker ie date picker

Comment: I have already tried it but please suggest me how to manage it with each button

Comment: Instead of UIButton why not just put a UITextField ? I assume those "+" are your "buttons". Just set the UITextField background color to [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: no u need to use the uicustom button And set the text like
[firstBtton setTitle:text controlState:uicontrolState normal]